# Telerik RadHtmlChart not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, bar-chart

I am populating a RadHtmlChart in the code behind based on data from the server. I think the problem is with how I am populating the data using ColumnSeries but I'm not entirely sure as this is my first foray into Telerik's charting.

Here is the code behind that deals with populating the chart:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dtDetail.Rows)
        {
            var series = new ColumnSeries();
            var series2 = new ColumnSeries();

            series.Name = row["StorageArea"].ToString();
            series.GroupName = row["StorageArea"].ToString();
            series.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32( row["NumBottles"].ToString()));
            series.Stacked = true;

            series2.Name = "Empty " + row["StorageArea"].ToString();
            series2.GroupName = row["StorageArea"].ToString();
            series2.Items.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row["EmptyPositions"].ToString()));
            series2.Stacked = true;

            RadChart1.PlotArea.Series.Add(series);
            RadChart1.PlotArea.Series.Add(series2);
        }
```

The ASPX page contains only the chart and a loading panel in AJAX.

Here is what the chart looks like with some dummy data in it:
[image: Bar Chart]

Thoughts or ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your dummy data that you're feeding in?

Comment: I'm giving each item a value of 5, the totals are added up in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but I guess you need two series with items for each row. FOr this you should create the series before the loop and only add items to the given series, instead of creating series for each row.